# Edge privacy concerns?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have concerns about the MS Edge browser. Recently while browsing, I downloaded ccleaner from piriform to check out the browser's cache, then  when I scanned, ccleaner found 45gb's of cache files.

- How can I stop Edge from eating my space?
- Is ccleaner legit(safe)?
- Is it possible that any virus caused it?
- Any antivirus suggestion?
- Why 45gb's?

(running windows 10 64bit)

Comment: If you care about privacy read the Windows 10 Privacy Policy. Essentially you have none.

Comment: Hmmm.  I doubt it's any issue with Edge. (Although it is *possible* that there is some odd bug still in the browser that is responsible; Edge is still in a bit rougher shape at this stage than Microsoft has been keen to admit. But still, I really would be quite surprised if Edge was the cause.)  If I had to take a wild guess at the real cause the first thing I would investigate would be if CCcleaner is counting old files & documents that Windows retained through your upgrade (assuming you upgraded) and tends to move to windows.old folders.  But that's just one possible cause to look at.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unfortunately, there is no way to stop Edge for storing cache files. In the other hand, you can switch to Firefox, and install a theme that will make it look like Edge.
2. CCleaner is totaly safe, when downloading it from piriform.com and not other fake sites
3. No, it is the way edge stores data.
4. BitDefender Free Edition is ideal and light.
5. The way edge works

If you are having privacy concerns, then Edge is not for you. Edge uses your browsing history to show you personalized advertisements, the way Google Chrome also works. If privacy matters, I recommend you to switch to Linux, or stop using Edge.